# VB insrt need to pull text from string

Tags: vb.net

I need to pull the data and then output in two lines. The input comes in as STREET/CITY/STATE/ZIP.  My code below works for street and city, at STATE it sends ST/ZIP to output.  I can seem to find my error??  Here is the code:

```
Private Sub btnEnter_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEnter.Click
    Dim Street As String, City As String, State As String, Zip As String
    Dim npos As Integer = 0, npos2 As Integer, npos3 As Integer = 0
    npos = (InStr(txtAddress.Text, "/"))
    npos2 = (InStr((npos + 1), txtAddress.Text, "/"))
    npos3 = (InStr((npos2 + 1), txtAddress.Text, "/"))
    Street = (Mid(txtAddress.Text, 1, (npos - 1)))
    City = (Mid(txtAddress.Text, (npos + 1), (npos2 - npos - 1)))
    State = (Mid(txtAddress.Text, (npos2 + 1), (npos3 - 1)))
    TextBox1.Text = Street & vbCrLf & City & " " & State

End Sub
```

Comment: i would recommend using [String.Split Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below, using [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which has been implemented specifically for these issues in .net.

```
Private Sub btnEnter_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEnter.Click
    Dim Street As String, City As String, State As String, Zip As String
    Dim data() as string

    data = txtAddress.Text.Split("/"c)
    Street = data(0)
    City = data(1)
    State = data(2)
    Zip = data(3)

    TextBox1.Text = Street & vbCrLf & City & " " & State

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however, error states that "split" is not a member of System.Windows.Forms.textbox???

Comment: Oups, sorry typo error, I missed the `.text` property. I updated the answer, can you please retry?